# Using bower components, like socket.io, with ember-cli

Tags: bower, ember-cli

There are some npm packages for client side libs, like ember-data. Those can be imported in the js files.

But the packages I install with bower don't get loaded.

I want to use Bootstrap and Socket.io in my Ember-cli app, but only Bootstrap has a ember-cli-* npm package, so I have to use the bower package for Socket.io (which is socket.io-client).

Comment: What does your bower.json file look like?

Comment: Problem was, I had to write the whole bower_components/... path and not only `import "socket.io"` like it worked with ember-data.I got it to work, but now the socket.io-client lib is failing with some strange "cannot read property 'agent' of undefined" now

Comment: @K.. yes, I think socket.io does not provide a valid bower package for use with Ember CLI. Having trouble with it as well at the moment.